# How do I center 3 Service boxes on a wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center on page 3 Service Boxes but no matter what I cant seem to center them on page. Im a total noob at this so any help would be awesome. Here is my current code. I am thinking I need to create each div in maybe a container or something and apply properties to that container? Or is this possibly an issue with the Avada theme using code block elements.

```css
.solutions_box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.30s ease 0s;
  border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-top: 4px solid #74AA50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #D3D3D3;
}

.solutions_box .solutions_icon {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  line-height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.30s ease 0s;
}

.solutions_box .solutions_icon {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #74AA50;
}

.solutions_box .solutions_icon i {
  color: #000000;
}

.solutions_box h3 {
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) 0s;
  font-family: 'TwCenMTStd-MediumCond', 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.service_list .list_item {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.30s linear 0s;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: solid #ececec 2px;
}

.service_list p {
  color: #666666;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.service_list:hover .list_item p {
  transition: .25s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  color: #74AA50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service_list:hover .list_item a {
  transition: .25s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  color: #74AA50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="solutions_box">

        <div class="solutions_icon">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </div>

        <h3>End User Support</h3>
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p>Solutions</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\soultions">
              <p> More Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p> Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="solutions_box">

        <div class="solutions_icon">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </div>

        <h3>End User Support</h3>
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p>Solutions</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\soultions">
              <p> More Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p> Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="solutions_box">

        <div class="solutions_icon">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </div>

        <h3>End User Support</h3>
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p>Solutions</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\soultions">
              <p> More Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p> Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap file into your html?

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">  This?

Comment: Yes. I`ve tested your code, and the services boxes are horizontally centred for me. You may have anything else on your site which is breaking it.

Comment: Yep, @caiovisk, same here, can't spot any problems: https://jsfiddle.net/c1frv6Lp/

Comment: I see, you are using `col-sm-6` wich on smaller screen will bring it to 2 columns, you can set col-sm-4, is it what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/c1frv6Lp/4/

Comment: Thats whats confusing me. Just a typical wordpress site with Avada theme. Only thing thats hand coded in the site too. Custom CSS is empty, besides what I have wrote. Every pen tool shows it lining up and all other elements line up.

Comment: No Its just slightly off to the right of the page on any screen. The col-md-4 is what I have been testing off of. I didnt know if it was trying to center all three and couldnt because I didnt code something right. I also figured maybe its because I have been coding for the better part of 8 hours and thought my first main code was wrong haha

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue was the container in which adding div class="container-fluid" for the most part corrected the issue. Seems to be more centered now with the exception of one object but that may be just an object placement issue. That being said the boxes are now lining up properly.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="solutions_box">

        <div class="solutions_icon">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </div>

        <h3>End User Support</h3>
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p>Solutions</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\soultions">
              <p> More Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p> Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="solutions_box">

        <div class="solutions_icon">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </div>

        <h3>End User Support</h3>
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p>Solutions</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\soultions">
              <p> More Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p> Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="solutions_box">

        <div class="solutions_icon">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </div>

        <h3>End User Support</h3>
        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p>Solutions</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\soultions">
              <p> More Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_list">
          <div class="list_item">
            <a href="\solutions">
              <p> Stuff </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```